# How to get list of files form multiple changesets using rest API

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, tfvc

I try to get the list of files to form multiple changesets using TFS rest API. I was able to successfully get a list of file for a single changeset using the following URL:

```
https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets/"{ChangesetsetID}/changes?api-version=4.1"
```

How to get a list of files to form multiple changesets?
I was used Javascript Ajax to get and show.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the list of files which belong to multiple changesets?

Comment: yes Andy you are right.

Comment: So, what is the point of doing this? Generally for the files added in source control,  you may change them based on your requirement/debug etc and then check in with changeset. That means , almost all files belong to multiple changesets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally for the files added in source control, you may change them based on your requirement/debug etc and then check in with changeset. That means , almost all files belong to multiple changesets...

So, In my opinion it's not meaningful to get list of files which belong to multiple changesets. Instead getting files which belongs to a single changset makes more sense...

Whatever, you can get the changesets that contain changes to the specified item/file with below REST API:

```
GET https://SERVER:8080/TFS/{CollectionName}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.itemPath=$/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/AuthSample/AuthSample/Program.cs&api-version=3.2
```

You can get the files' name and call the REST API in a loop to check each file, if the count of the value from the response is more than 1, then the file should be the one you want to be retrieved...

PowerShell example for your reference: (Change the `path` in the body, e.g. in below sample I checked the files under path : `$/ScrumProject/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1` )

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$user = "domain\name",
   [string]$token = "password",
   [string]$exportpath = "D:\temp"

)
$filename = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + "-" + "FileList.csv"

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get path of the files from a sepcific folder 
$fileurl = "$collectionurl/_apis/tfvc/itemBatch?api-version=3.2"

$body = '{"includeContentMetadata":true,"includeLinks":null,"itemDescriptors":[{"path":"$/ScrumProject/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1","versionType":5,"recursionLevel":4}]}'

$pathresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $fileurl -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"-Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$paths = $pathresponse.value.path

Clear-Host
#Get changesets that contain changes to the specified item/file
foreach ($path in $paths )
{
$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/_apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.itemPath=$path&api-version=3.2" 
$changesetResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$count = $changesetResponse.count

#Displsy and export the matching files to a *.csv file

 if ($count -gt 1)
 {
  Write-host $path
  $path | Add-Content $exportpath\$filename
 }
}
```

[image]